# c++ how to prevent function parameter evaluation

Tags: c++

Is it possible to prevent function parameter evaluation?
As I don't want to evaluate the function parameter in some situation.

E.g.
To log a debug message,

```
void log(int severity, ...);
```

I want to log a message

```
log(DEBUG, "%s", getErrorMsg().c_str());
```

If the severity is DEBUG, the log function is just to return in release binary.
So, it is not necessary to evaluate getErrorMsg();

Comment: This might be relevant (to anyone who comes across this old thread): https://foonathan.net/2017/06/lazy-evaluation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any parameter you pass to a function will always be evaluated just before entry to the function.

You probably want to pass something like a pointer, so the pointer itself is what's evaluated, and you only invoke a function via that pointer when/if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. May I know how to declare a generic function pointer so that I can pass?

Comment: Apparently in this case you want something like `char const *(*)()` (pointer to function taking no arguments and returning a pointer to char). Though some people don't like it, if you have `std::function` available, it might be worth considering.

Comment: Yes. Since the log function accepts variable parameter, the parameter may be log(DEBUG, "%d, %s", iValue, getSth(iValue).c_str()); Is it possible to cater for all cases?

Comment: @MichaelD: No, not really, at least without some other substantial changes. I suppose you could probably come up with something using expression templates, but it would be non-trivial, and pretty much require at least some change to the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use macros:

```
#define log(severity, ...) if (severity!=DEBUG) log_impl(severity,__VA_ARGS__);
```